# How to trigger EventBridge with an HTTP request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-event-bridge

How do I create a rule that captures an HTTP GET that has some data and schedules the running of a lambda function at a specific time? I can write the lambda function but I am having trouble with creating an API endpoint to which I can send a "fetch" GET request. I tried creating an HTTP API in the API Gateway service. It returns this output:

```
{
"message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I am not much familiar with AWS. Please help me with creating a simple endpoint in AWS to which my app can send a GET request with some data, which will trigger an EventBridge rule to schedule the running of a lambda function at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an API Gateway or a separate Lambda function.

To schedule the running of a specific Lambda function you can call the EventBridge put rule API.

You can find examples of the [EventBridge user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html).